# Script (bash) to automatically start/restart nginx (if it fails)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, bash, ubuntu-9.04, uwsgi

Can someone help me to setup nginx on my box?
I have compiled it (i'm using it to run Django app using uwsgi_rs).

Its running OK but i have to start it manually. How can i setup it to autorun? And start it again (automatically) if it ware killed? I'm talking about nginx and uwsgi...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find an [Ubuntu 9 compatible](http://wiki.nginx.org/Nginx-init-ubuntu) init script for nginx on the nginx wiki. It also contains instructions on how to install it so that it is started when the system boots.

Comment: I suspect the "right" answer here might be to write an Upstart script.

Comment: Does Upstart can restart nginx process? If it were killed? I saw http://wiki.nginx.org/Nginx-init-ubuntu script but i'm not sure it support auto-restarting... Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to take a look at [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/). I've grown quite fond of it. There are packages for it on most distributions and the setup is not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the capabilities of nginx, so I just assume you've checked (`man nginx`) that it doesn't have an option to automatically respawn.
You can create (as root) a simple script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1 ]
  do /usr/local/sbin/nginx
done
```

save as, for example, `/usr/local/bin/loopnginx.sh`, then do `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/loopnginx.sh` and finally, in the init script you mentioned, replace the line

```
DAEMON=/usr/local/sbin/nginx
```

with:

```
DAEMON=/usr/local/bin/loopnginx.sh
```